# Reference for Bethe Ansatz solution of 1D spinless Hubbard model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, integrable-systems, spin-chains

I want to numerically solve 1D spinless Hubbard model using Bethe Ansatz. Can you provide me some online references for that.